# Which approach is more expensive to restrict an ArrayList to have only DISTINCT entries?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashset

I have contacts that are being added to an arraylist, now some contacts are common in other applications so duplicate entries are also saved in that.

I'm aware of two approaches to resolve this situation, I'm not sure which approach should I follow ?

first:

```
String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                temp.add(name);

                if (!contactList.contains(name)) {
                    contactList.add(name);}
```

second:

Adding it to hashset as it doesn't allow duplicate entries and then adding it back to arraylist-

```
     String name = getStrin(...);
        contactList.add(name);

// after the loop has completed adding all elements
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
        hs.addAll(contactList);
        contactList.clear();
        contactList.addAll(hs);
```

Comment: Why not to add values to HashSet right from the start when you read from cursor?

Comment: yeah this also looks good. I think this one is more efficient, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the second way, as it is better, and optimized for distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

EVen when you add it to a HashSet, the HashSet will perform operations to check if entry exists and will have to reorganize itself to accommodate the new entry albeit in a more optimized way. So I don't think there is any major advantage to be gained by going for the second method. Plus you are doing addAll() and clear() operations in method 2, so any optimization gained by HashSet usage might be offset by these.

I suggest you go for first method itself, But you should test both methods and measure whichever is better for your specific test cases and application requirements.

Comment: I can't notice any difference as data set is not that big and presence of ample resources. I was asking in general- which approach is normally recommended because this kind of situation comes very often.

Comment: In that case, I would still personally go for first method for the reasons stated earlier.